# Why Snap.svg animates only some attributes in group?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Why is that Snap.svg animates only some attributes of grouped elements? In this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/przemoo83/en53w2f4/) when elements are grouped they animate opacity and transform but not radius. When animation is applied to a single element all attributes are animated. I don't get it.

```
(function(){
var s = Snap("#svg");
var c1 = s.circle(10, 10, 10);
var c2 = s.circle(50, 20, 10);
var c3 = s.circle(50, 100, 10);
var points = s.group(c1,c2);
var states = 
[
    {       
            transform: 'r90,25,25',
        r: 10,
        opacity: 0.3

    }, 
    {       
            transform: 'r90,200,200',
        r: 5,
        opacity: 1
    }, 
];
function animateGroup(el, i) {
    points.animate(states[i], 1000, function() {
    animateGroup(el, ++i in states ? i : 0);
    })
}
function animateOne(el, i) {
    c3.animate(states[i], 1000, function() {
    animateOne(el, ++i in states ? i : 0);
    })
}
animateGroup(points, 0);
animateOne(c3,0);

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a group doesn't have a radius attribute. You can only animate attributes that apply to that specific element (of which one is a group).

If you want to animate several circles for example, you would need to use a 'set' and apply the animation to that set (or grab a set with a selectAll or something and loop over it with a .forEach() method).

You could try something like...

```
points.selectAll('circle').animate({ r: '20' }, 2000 );
```

But this may not quite work with a separate object that needs different radiuses, so you may need to just  use a typical loop otherwise.

```
points.selectAll('circle').forEach( function( el, index ) {
   //use the index to access from the object, eg states[ index ] maybe ??
   el.animate( states[ index ], 2000 ) // untested
} );
```

Comment: So how do I go around it? Loop through all group elements?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the answer. If you use a set, with the later versions of Snap, you can apply an animation to the set I think. Otherwise you can use a forEach over them all (the same thing kinda happens behind the scenes, it's just a case of which is more convenient).

Comment: Have just added an example.